# rotating text slightly—should I use css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a block of text slightly like below:

[image]

Can this be done with css or do I need to use javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a cross browser fashion using CSS3's [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform), and a `filter` for IE.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/dRQaw/

[This is the magical tool used to generate the cross-browser CSS.](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/index.html)

```
<div id="skewed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu metus nisi. Integer non adipiscing massa. Etiam et diam magna. Mauris sit amet arcu dui, a malesuada erat.</div>

#skewed {
    font: 21px Impact, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc
}
#skewed {
     width:             350px;
     height:            140px;

     -moz-transform:    skew(-5deg, -5deg);
     -o-transform:      skew(-5deg, -5deg);
     -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg, -5deg);
     transform:         skew(-5deg, -5deg);
}
```

Comment: Nice contribution thirtydot, I'm going to revoke mine.

Comment: Funny, I just clicked to upvote yours because it's the same idea I have but less fleshed out and got a message "deleted posts can't be voted on" ;)

Comment: Well if anyone's interested in the crazy example link here it is: http://www.useragentman.com/tests/cssSandpaper/cube3.html

Comment: If you don't care about IE7/8 you can use the `-ms-transform` vendor prefix for IE9, but if cross browser support is needed this is the better solution.

Comment: @J82: I picked `skew` because it looked like your text was skewed. However, I see now that it looks more like a rotated italic font. You can replace `skew` with `rotate`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dRQaw/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS3 transforms:

```
p {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
```

Comment: Use this one, its more complete.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be CSS-only. You can use JS to manipulate the CSS, but JS itself has nothing to do whatsoever with presentation, other than being one method of changing the presentation rules.

Comment: Who knows. Some people just can't deal with negativity?

Comment: @kennis and Marc: I downvoted because I didn't think this was a useful answer, and misleading at worst in regards to the "has nothing to do *whatsoever* with presentation". It also doesn't mention anything about how to use CSS to accomplish this. It only barely answers the literal question: `Can this be done with css or do I need to use javascript?` Which of course, most likely means that OP doesn't know the CSS solution. So, am I being too harsh with the downvotes?

Comment: Eh, I don't know. I agree with the idea that "answers" should generally provide a solution - but I do think it's important that people understand that in this particular case, Javascript would only be manipulating CSS properties. It can't rotate anything on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS. Here is CSS that will work in Firefox, Opera and Safari/Chrome.

```
#textToRotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```